# How can I convert a single character into a char* with strlen = 1?

Tags: c, string, char

I've trying to do this but I can't find the right way. I have this :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char a = 'a';
  char b[1] = " ";
  strcat(b,a);
  printf ("%s",b);
  return 0;
}
```

I know it's wrong. How can I fix this code in order to turn `'a'` into `"a"` ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling

Comment: when you use strcat it adds `\0` at the end of new string, you must create `char b[2]`

Comment: `char b[1] = " ";
 strcat(b,a);` --> `char b[3] = " "; strncat(b, &a, 1);` or `char b[2] = ""; strncat(b, &a, 1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char a = 'a';
    char b[2] = " ";
    b[0] = a;
    printf ("%s",b);
    return 0;
}
```

A c string is just an array of characters - if you want to set individual characters in that string, you can do so exactly as you would any other array.

One thing you missed though is that c strings have to be 1 longer than the number of characters you want to store - to store the terminating `\0`.